# Difference between JQuery $.each loop and JS for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5"];

function findValueInArrayJQ(array,value) {
  $.each(arr, (index, a) => {
    if(a == value) {
        return true;
    }
  });
  return false;  
}

function findValueInArrayJS(array,value) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == value)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(findValueInArrayJQ(arr,"1"));
console.log(findValueInArrayJS(arr,"1"));
```

Output

```
false
true
```

As far as I know both of them should give me the same output. Why the first one give me false output?

Comment: You can also use `return arr.some(el => el == value);`. Or even simply `return arr.includes(value)`.

Comment: Now I know that I have to make temp boolian variable and return with that. But why do I have to do that.

Comment: Because `return` applies to the enclosing function. Which is in jQuery case the `(index, a) => {...}` arrow function.

Comment: @Ivar okey, that is a fair answare, thanks